# Search a corridor bigger than 2000 meters

Tags: here-api

I have created a custom layer with POI (level=8).

I am using the [HERE](https://www.here.com) library. In particular, I'm searching in `corridor.json` all POI along the route, but I can only search with a radius of 2000 meters or less.

I need to increase the radius, but this results in an error: 400 Bad Request, Invalid search radius, must be between 0 and 2000.0.

URL that I use (without app ID or code): [link](https://cle.api.here.com/2/search/corridor.json?app_id=%3CMyAppID%3E&app_code=%3CMyAppCode%3E&corridor=51.01,3.40;51.01,3.37;51.00,3.34;51.00,3.33;50.99,3.30;50.99,3.25;50.98,3.21;50.97,3.17;50.98,3.13;50.97,3.10;50.96,3.09;50.96,3.05;50.94,3.03;50.93,3.00;50.92,2.97;50.91,2.94;50.87,2.92;50.87,2.91;50.87,2.90;50.87,2.89&layer_ids=%3CMyLayerID%3E&radius=5000)

Is this by design, or can I increase the radius?

Thx,
Andy

Comment: Doesn't the error message already answer this? **must be between 0 and 2000.0** seems pretty clear and specific.

Comment: Indeed, hence the question: is it possible to increase the radius. HERE somethimes offers options to change such settings, so I was wondering if this was the case. Imagine searching for a gas station along the route, then 2000 meters is far to narrow for certain areas

Comment: @AndyC , Yes the limit as of now is 2000 which is hard coded. and yes, for searching gas stations along the route this is too narrow.
For this use case we have the "search POIs along route isoline", it offers real driving distance and/or real driving time from the route rather than airline distance (which doesn't help if there is no motorway exit nearby).Maybe you can take a look whether this fits.https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/calculate_poi_along_isoline_route

Comment: also we have created an internal case to check if the radius can increase.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I already checked the Poi along isoline and got it working, but the request often times-out if the radius is more than 5km.

Answer (score 0):

**radius** is the correct parameter that can be increased to magnify and specify the search capabilities of API.

radius [radius=100], specifies the buffer search radius in meters.

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/search/corridor.json
?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
&corridor=52.51978,3.388211;
52.5198326,13.3882084;
52.5198402,13.3883495;
52.5147705,13.3891602;
52.514758,13.389155
&radius=100
&layer_ids=30
```

Comment: I know the radius can be increased, the question was if the maximum of 2000m could be increased. I have noticed that the maximum is now 5000m, I will check if this is sufficient